# Best Practice to query database when inflating ListView/RecyclerView item

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a ListView/RecyclerView. Now, I want to add more information for each item and the information could be found in database according to the item value. How would you guy achieve it??

For the best practice, should I query database in the background thread? Should I cancel the query if user scrolling fast?

Comment: Typically, for small to medium-sized collections, you would load all of that data before populating the `ListView` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "best practice" AFAIK, but the following is a short summary of your options:

**Query on UI thread as the user scrolls**

It is usually a very bad practice to execute queries on UI thread in general. It is a sin to do this in ListView.

That said, there are ORM libraries that perform lazy loading of nested objects on UI thread (e.g. GreenDAO). People use these libraries in applications that have ListViews and it even works alright for some of them.

I would strongly advice against this method.

**Query of all items ahead of time**

As @CommonsWare mentioned, for small to medium collections you can just load the entire dataset into memory on background thread and then bind it to the ListView. You will need to show some kind of progress indication while the data is being loaded.

The definition of "small" and "medium" is very vague, but I'd say that if you are sure that the dataset will not be larger than few MBs, then this method can work pretty well.

The drawback of this method is that the user will need to wait for the entire dataset to be loaded and bound to the ListView. Depending on the size of the dataset and the complexity of database scheme this might take a while.

**Query a predefined number of items initially, and then perform additional queries as the user scrolls**

This is the most complex scheme of all, but it is inevitable in some cases (e.g. "infinite list").

The idea is to get some predefined number of items into the ListView, and then track user's interactions in order to supply additional items.

For example, you can fetch 100 items initially, and then fetch additional 100 when the user scrolls to the end of the list.

An optimization of this scheme would be to fetch additional items before the user gets to the end of the list (let's say when he scrolled through 50 items). This allows to create a truly "infinite list" behavior.

Note that if your collection is very large, you will need to take care not only of adding a new items as the user scrolls, but also of removing "previous" items in order to avoid out of memory crash.

**Query of additional information for items that are already shown**

Sometimes you would like to perform some additional query after the item is already shown.

In this case, just perform the query in the background and bind the data to the item.

One caveat of this task is that if the view of the item is recycled (as is the case in RecyclerView by default), then when your background fetch is done the target View might show totally different item. Binding the returned data to this View would be a mistake.

One way of handling this is to cancel the fetch. However, this is cumbersome and error prone in practice.

The easier way is just set `transientState` flag when the query is initiated, and clear it when the query is completed.